# Rolling back to a previous version of OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, xcode-simulator, instruments

I installed the latest version of Mavericks and it broke some stuff (instruments) which I cannot afford to have broken.  Is there a way to roll back to my previous release?  Am currently on 10.9.2 and want to go to 10.9.1 or 10.9.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: rolling back is not a picnic (since more problems could appear), so lets try to repair the damage first if possible, lets us know more details on that.

Comment: If instruments is broken note there has been a new version of Xcode - I double Apple would leave developers without that tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my pet peeves with O/S X is there is not an uninstall feature for patches, upgrades and even apps. One of the (VERY) few things that Windows has that I wish the Mac had.

Unfortunately the only real way to do this is to wipe the drive, install the pervisous version, assuming you have the installer or can find it and restore from backup.

What I usually do before a major OR point upgrade is to attach a USB HD and clone the drive. Then I verify it boots from the clone. Only then do I do an upgrade. So if the upgrade breaks something all I have to do is back up the few changed files and restore from my clone.

As for Time Machine, you can't restore an O/S from Time Machine as it does not backup system files. However once you have reinstalled the O/S Time Machine can take you the rest of the way.

Probably NOT what you want to hear but that's the only solution I have ever found...

Comment: That is a good advice. As said it is Not a picnic! whipping the whole drive and reinstalling it, and please explain how does one gets the 10.9.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Back up the files you need to an external harddrive (or TimeCapsule?) - or clone your disk, there's tools available for it
2. Format your disk to a clean HFS+
3. Install a clean version of OSX Mavericks using 10.9 installer
4. Put back the files you need

Answer (score -1):

Use TimeMachine for backups and simply rollback if something goes wrong at updating OS X.

Comment: Do you have any experience (or references to other articles on the web) about whether TM can be used to rollback an OS X upgrade? If yes please add this to the answer because the steps might not be obvious for everybody.